# The method getId() in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: android

I am trying to implement checkboxes list so after selecte the multiple checkboxes I want to store them in ArrayList and after clicking the button send them to the server. At the momenant I am getting the following error in the is statement

> The method getId() in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)

as wellas at this line `cb = new CheckBox(this);`

> The final local variable cb may already have been assigned

How can I fix that?

```
 private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        //final CheckBox cb;

        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setText(items.get(i).toString());
            cb.setId(i);
            ll.addView(cb);

        }
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
        btn.setText("submit");
        ll.addView(btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i : items) {
                    if (cb.getId(i).isChecked()) {

                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Edit:

I have deleted the `final CheckBox cb;`  and assign the object in the for loop `CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);` but I am getting in the if statement this error `cb cannot be resolved` How  can I assign it to get ride of the error?

When I assign the Checkbox as class variable I am getting this error `The method getId() in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)` in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
      CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
      cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
      cb.setId(i);
      ll.addView(cb);

   }
```

use this rather

Comment: But like this I cant access my `cb` in the if statement I ma getting `cb cannot be resolved`

Comment: what if statement the button if statement? wait Sir, the arraylist consist of ids of checked checkboxes or the items in a checkbox? elaborate on that part, and i will help you.@MrAsker